# c# Android how to put Enum into bundle

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, serialization, enums

I am trying to Place an Enum value into A bundle using the below code.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.PutSerializable("key", NavigationType.HOME);
```

However I am getting an error
**Cannot convert from Enums.NavigationType to Java.IO.ISerializable**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set an enum as a serializable object, which is not possible. One easy way to do this is passing it as string, and then convert it on the other end, like this:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.PutString("key", NavigationType.HOME.toString());
```

and when you fetch the arguments:

```
Enum.TryParse(args.GetStringExtra("key"), out NavigationType navigationType);
```

Comment: Would that have much of an impact on performance? would I be better off just using an int id value?

Comment: The issue will not be with performance, but with possible parse errors, which in this case i don't think it will happen because you are using static names. You can try to send int IDs instead of strings, but I don't think you will have any gain in performance.